# DB2 Connection pool in Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, db2, pool

### Well...

i already have copied files :**db2jcc4.jar  db2jcc.jar** which I get from my db2 server.
Now Im trying to make a connection pool in glassfish as a :
*javax.sql.DataSource*
with :
*Datasource class name: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2DataSource*
... data in url, name and password are 100% correct because I can connect to that DB with standalone application. When all is configured and Im trying to ping my server Ive getting this:

*Ping Connection Pool for DB2ConnPool is Failed. Ping failed Exception - Connection could not be allocated because: [jcc][10389][12245][4.7.85] Niepowodzenie podczas ładowania biblioteki rodzimej db2jcct2, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no db2jcct2 in java.library.path: ERRORCODE=-4472, SQLSTATE=null Please check the server.log for more details.*

For all non-polish users :
"Niepowodzenie podczas ładowania biblioteki rodzimej"
is like:
"Failure while loading library"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer already given by Tom is correct, and the solution is to add a "driverType = 4" in the "additional properties" of Glassfish's connection pool configuration page.

Here's a link to an article in spanish, but may be useful: http://www.unixlibre.org/articulos.jsp?cve=61

Answer (score 1):

The driver is trying to load a native library called db2jcct2 - that will be in a file called db2jcct2.dll on Windows, or libdb2jcct2.so on unix. For some reason, it is not on the library search path.

So, do two things:

1. Make sure you have the library in a directory somewhere
2. Make sure you set the java.library.path system variable to include that directory